# Does mainnet and babylonnet create peer connections differently?

Tags: peers

Does mainnet and babylonnet create peer connections differently?
My current scenario on AWS:
I’ve got a VPC containing 2 EC2 instances that are supposed to independently run. I’m using the docker setup.
For mainnet this seems to work as expected, however for babylonnet only 1 node manages to find peers and sync. The other node/ec2 instance gets stuck on Too few connections (0).
Things I’ve tried:
Clear the node to get a new identity and restart => Same result: Too few connections
Build from source on non working babylonnet node  => successful, node started syncing
Instead of 2 instances use 10 => still only 1 managed to sync
Run 2 different docker environments on my local machine => Both instances found peers and started syncing
What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 2):

The node is using a default port to be connected "to the outside". If two machines are using the same port on the same machine it will conflict. You need specify a different one using the **--net-addr PORT** option when running your node.